# dual problem of SDP

Tags: convex-optimization, duality, semidefinite-programming

suppose we have the following optimization problem:

\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\min }\limits_{{\bf{X}},{\bf{x}}} \,\,Tr\left( {{\bf{XA}}} \right) + 2{{\bf{a}}^H}{\bf{x}} + b\\
s.t:\,\,\,\,\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\bf{X}}&{\bf{x}}\\
{{{\bf{x}}^H}}&1
\end{array}} \right]\succcurlyeq {\bf{0}},\,\,\,\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{c^2}}&{{{\bf{x}}^H}}\\
{\bf{x}}&1
\end{array}} \right] \succcurlyeq {\bf{0}}
\end{array}
the matrix $\bf{A}$ is a hermitian matrix but not necessary to be semidefinite.
I want to know how can I write the dual form for the above optimization problem?

Comment: this looks like a standard exercise in the duality theory of SDPs, apart from there seems to be a typo in the objective function (unless there is an extra assumption that $x$ is real).

Comment: I agree with Dima. However, it might help the OP to notice that the objective is linear, regardless of $A$ not being psd.